# How to make a HttpWebRequest and sending Stream ( not sending byte[] )

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

When i using the HttpWebRequest - i need to send byte[] ( as far as i know ) 
So i doing it in this code

```
            _argRequest[] = .... 

            using( Stream reqStream = _httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() )
            {
                if( _argRequest != null )
                {
                    reqStream.Write( _argRequest, 0, _argRequest.Length );
                    reqStream.Flush();
                    reqStream.Close();
                }
            }
```

But is it possible to send Stream and not byte[] - ( without casting the Stream to byte[] )

Thanks

Comment: No. You're sending an HTTP/1.1 request, which has no notion of "streams". All it can send are bytes. Please explain your actual problem.

Comment: `Stream.CopyTo` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @CodeCaster ? Stream is sequence of bytes... Not sure what your statement mean...

Comment: And I don't know what OP's statement means that he wants to _"send Stream not byte[]"_. You can't _"send a stream"_, hence my question. If it's clear what OP actually wants to do (for example _"upload a file without having the entire file in a byte array"_), an actual solution can be given instead of guesses.

Comment: @CodeCaster I read "send Stream" as "send all content of an instance of `class Stream` (or derived type)"... But I agree that it may not be what OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) can copy stream without (externally visible) usage of `byte[]`:

```
 streamToPost.CopyTo(reqStream);
```